# Не удается преобразовать из "NumSharp.NDArray" в "Numpy.NDarray"

Tags: c#, keras

Как преобразовать из NumSharp.NDArray в Numpy.NDarray ?

```
using NumSharp;
using NumSharp.Bitmap;
using Keras.Net;


var model = Keras.Models.Model.LoadModel("keras_model.h5");
Bitmap imbit = GetImageBitmap();
var ndarray = imbit.ToNDArray(flat: false, copy: false, discardAlpha: true);
var normalized_image_array = (ndarray.astype(NumSharp.np.float32) / 127.0) - 1;
       
MessageBox.Show(model.Predict(normalized_image_array).ToString());
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вместо NumSharp нужно использовать Numpy. [Примеры](https://github.com/SciSharp/Keras.NET/tree/master/Examples) программ на C#

Comment: @АлексейОбухов у класса ImageUtil только загрузка картинки через patch до картинки. Через Bitmap image не возможно, что очень плохо

Answer (score 1):

Нужно преобразовать "NumSharp.NDArray" в "Numpy.NDarray":

```
var fArr = normalized_image_array.ToArray<float>().Select(x => (float)x).ToArray();
```

---

```
        Bitmap imbit = GetImageBitmap();
        var ndarray = imbit.ToNDArray(flat: false, copy: true, discardAlpha: true);
        var normalized_image_array = (ndarray.astype(NumSharp.np.float32) / 127.0) - 1;
        var fArr = normalized_image_array.ToArray<float>().Select(x => (float)x).ToArray();
        Numpy.NDarray npArr = Numpy.np.array(fArr, Numpy.np.float32).reshape(1, 224, 224, 3);
        MessageBox.Show(model.Predict(npArr).ToString());
```